# R: generate a new column based on groups and conditions

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 4 columns (part of it shown below).

The first column shows groups ordered by numbers: 1, 2, ....

I want to generate a new column "value4".
For each group, if the group size is bigger than 2 (>=3), and all the values in column "value1" are bigger than 2 (>2) or smaller than -2 (< -2), then the median of the corresponding values in column "value3" are calculated and put in column "value4" for each row of this group. Otherwise, the values from "value2" is taken to column "value4".

```
g   value1   value2  value3
1     1.1      8       1
1     1.2      8       1
1     1.3      9       1
2     3        10      5
2     4        11      5
2     5        0       4
2     6        1       6
3     -3       2       5
3     -4       3       10
3     -5       4       0
4     -3       1       0
4     -4       1       0
```

The output will be:

```
g   value1   value2  value3  value4
1     1.1      8       1       8  # for group "1", all the values in "value1" are <2, so the values from column "value2" are taken
1     1.2      8       1       8
1     1.3      9       1       9
2     3        10      5       5  # for group "2", all the values in "value1" are >2, median of numbers 5,5,4,6 from column "value3" is calculated  
2     4        11      5       5
2     5        0       4       5
2     6        1       6       5
3     -3       2       5       5  # for group "3", all the values in "value1" are < -2, median of numbers 5,10,0 from column "value3" is calculated      
3     -4       3       10      5
3     -5       4       0       5
4     -3       1       0       1  # group size less than 3, so the values from column "value2" are taken
4     -4       1       0       1
```

I think I can use aggregate(), but I don't know how to integrate the conditions. I appreciate your time and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the package `data.table` as follows:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, value4 := if(.N > 2 & (all(value1 > 2) | all(value1 < -2))) median(value3) else value2, g]
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the condition, we can use a `if/else` condition utilizing the groupsize (`n()`) and if `all` value1 less than -2 or greater than 2,then get the `median` of 'value3' or `else` return 'value2'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%       
   group_by(g) %>%
   mutate(value4 = if(n() > 2 & (all(value1 > 2)| all(value1 < -2))) median(value3) 
       else value2)
# A tibble: 12 x 5
# Groups:   g [4]
#       g value1 value2 value3 value4
#   <int>  <dbl>  <int>  <int>  <dbl>
# 1     1    1.1      8      1      8
# 2     1    1.2      8      1      8
# 3     1    1.3      9      1      9
# 4     2    3       10      5      5
# 5     2    4       11      5      5
# 6     2    5        0      4      5
# 7     2    6        1      6      5
# 8     3   -3        2      5      5
# 9     3   -4        3     10      5
#10     3   -5        4      0      5
#11     4   -3        1      0      1
#12     4   -4        1      0      1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(g = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L), value1 = c(1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 3, 4, 5, 6, -3, -4, -5, -3, 
-4), value2 = c(8L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
1L), value3 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 10L, 0L, 0L, 
0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Comment: I don't think this is correct.  `g` (and `g1`) appear to be group IDs in the example but you are evaluating it as a value.

Comment: @MokeEire I think you are right.  I will update.  I was thinking it as value instead of n()

Answer (score 0):

This is an ideal situation for [case_when()](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html).*

You would like `value4` to be calculated based on the following condition:

If Group size > 2 **and** the absolute value of all `value1` in a group > 2 => take the median of `value3`. Otherwise use `value2`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(g) %>%
  mutate(value4 = case_when( (n() > 2) & (all(abs(value1) > 2)) ~ median(value3), 
                            T ~ value2)
```

*One would think we could use `if_else()` here because there is only one condition but for some reason, it was failing when using `all()` in the condition.  I think it was returning multiple values?  Unclear, but maybe someone else could explain.